# Using foreach binding without changing context in Knockout.js

Tags: templates, knockout.js, data-binding, foreach

Is it possible to use foreach binding without changing it's context?

For example, here's my template:

```
<div data-bind="foreach:{data:users,as:'user'}">
  <div data-bind="template:{name:'userAvatar',data:user}"></div>
</div>

<div data-bind="template:{name:'userAvatar',data:currentUser}"></div>

<script type="text/template" id="userAvatar">
  <img data-bind="attr:{src:avatarUrl}">
</script>
```

So I use template 'userAvatar' inside the foreach loop and outside it. And now I want to perform some action when user clicks to an avatar. For example, my model is

```
var MyModel = function() {
  this.users = [
    {name:"user1",avatarUrl:"url1"},
    {name:"user2",avatarUrl:"url2"}
  ];
  this.currentUser = {name:"user3",avatarUrl:"url3"};
  this.openProfile = function() {
    // opening user profile
  }
}
```

This case if I want to call 'openProfile' action in template I have to use $parent.openProfile when the template lies outside foreach and $parents[1].openProfile, when it's inside it.

I can copy link to openProfile to each user object or specify the location of openProfile method when I call the template binding, but is there more natural solution?

P.S. And I can't use $root variable because in real world my $root lies 10 levels upper of theese models.

Comment: This is an example and here I can use $root, but in real situation I have multiple nested models so my $root is rather far and it even doesn't know about current models and their methods.

Comment: I know that this is a hack but you can use a `with` around your currentUser tempalte... `<!-- ko with: currentUser --> <div data-bind="template:{name:'userAvatar',data: $data}"></div><!-- /ko -->` Then you can use `$parents[1].openProfile` in both cases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My [Repeat](https://github.com/mbest/knockout-repeat) binding does a similar action as foreach, but without creating a child context.

```
<div data-bind="repeat:users" 
    data-repeat-bind="template:{name:'userAvatar',data:$item()}"></div>
```

Another option (maybe better) that applies to your example, because it uses `template`, is the [`foreach` option](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/template-binding.html#note_2_using_the_foreach_option_with_a_named_template) of `template`:

```
<div data-bind="template:{name:'userAvater',foreach:users}"></div>
```

Comment: I just realized that there's a better solution, which I've added to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert users array to Object and implement the click action in that object.

```
function User(name,avatarUrl) {
   var self = this;

   this.name = ko.observable(name);
   this.avatarUrl = ko.observable(avatarUrl);

   this.openProfile = function() {
      ....
   }
}


users = ko.observableArray([new User(...),new User(...)]);
```

I think that action naturally belongs to User model not your root model.